# Call a local (in memory) Twisted

Tags: twisted, mod-wsgi, apache

there's a way to run twisted without expose it behind a network port?

We have a wsgi servlet running behind apache/mod_wsgi.

This servlet need to send a message to a local Twisted instance. But, we are not finding a way to run this.

Our expected architecture layers:

**`apache_httpd > mod_wsgi > servlet > twisted`**

There's a way to run it?

Regards,

And Past

Answer (score 3):

Twisted can accept input via [standard input](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/api/twisted.internet.stdio.html), via a [UNIX socket](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorUNIX.html) (also known as a "socket file"), and via a [locally bound TCP network port](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTCP.html).  None of these need necessarily expose your Twisted service to the outside world.

Comment: We were trying to call twisted locally, in same memory&cpu space. But, we realized that python don't keeps an Application Context ready for distinct stateless HTTP requests. So, for each request, we need to start up a new twisted thread and other resources. We decided to keep an twisted instance using HTTP behind httpd reverse proxy. Regards